# Queue::push() not sending queues to IronMQ

Tags: php, laravel-4, ironmq

I have a file upload form where an image is being uploaded first to my server and then to Imgur. The upload to Imgur is supposed to be queued. So, once a new file is uploaded, I do a push:

```
Queue::push('JobController@someJob',['v1'=>'something','v2'=>'something']);
```

I used this to subscribe to the queue:

```
php artisan queue:subscribe name http://url
```

Now, I can see that this is working because I can see the subscription in IronMQ

[image: subscribed successfully]

However, when I do an upload, the image uploads fine in my server and shows no error. But there are no message sent to IronMQ:

[image: No message shown on ironmq]

Thus, those Imgur uploads are not happening either. I have tested everything and searched extensively, I haven't found any solutions to this yet. Any idea whats happening?

Comment: Make sure you're checking the messages in the same region you're sending them to. There's a region selector (aws, rackpace etc) at the top of a page on a project view.

Comment: Yes the same region. Never changed it and still checked all. Nothing.

Comment: DO the laravel logs show anything?

Comment: Nope. Nothing about queuing or queue Marshall. Weird

Comment: A Queue is a FIFO (First in, First out) data structure. Are you absolutely sure that _Laravel_, a _PHP_ framework, implements it _correctly_?

Comment: I'm sure since it's working now and has always worked. And the queues are being served as they are queued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: 
I was stupidly calling `Queue::push (...)` after I had already done `return Response::json('done',200)`.
Since the function ends in return the queue was not being called.